# Error when storing data from an SQL database into a PHP table

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am learning PHP and SQL, and I am currently trying to output data from a preexisting SQL database table into a table created via PHP. As of now, I am just trying to get the data from a single column and output the data into a column in my PHP table. I am able to correctly gather the data one row at a time using the code:

```
"SELECT column FROM table WHERE row1='variable1' AND row2='variable2'"
```

with `WHERE` pinpointing which row should be outputted within `column`.

However, I am having issues with storing the data to output the proper result. I am currently using the code below to output the row with the data from the SQL table:

```
if($con->query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE row1='variable1' AND row2='variable2'")) {
    if($output= $con->use_result()) {
        while($row = $output->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>".$output."</td>";
    }
}}
```

However, when I run the code, it merely blanks the row where I should be outputting the data. Could anyone please point me in the right direction to properly store and output the row into a table? It would be much appreciated. Let me know if anymore of my code or other information is needed.

EDIT: I should mention that the table is being generated via an HTML button.

Comment: Try `$row['column']`... because `Fetch a result row as an associative array`.

Comment: Which data you want to outputting on table ? I can see you didn't mentioned any field name in while loop. You need to put mysql table filed name in loop which you want to output in table. Like as  echo "<td>".$output['column']."</td>";

Comment: OP uses `$row` so I think it should be `$row['column']` instead of `$output['column']`.

Comment: Oh, yea good point @Irvin. Corrected.

Comment: since you are looping you must use the `$row` index `column`

Comment: @chris85 I corrected it to `$row['column']` though the row in the table still oddly disappears when I run it. I should have mentioned that (and I will update the OP) I am using an HTML button to generate the table in PHP. The table itself generates fine, it's just the data from the SQL table that isn't properly outputting.

Comment: Can you add more context? Does `$row['column']` have HTML in it? If you `var_dump($row['column']);` what are you getting?

Comment: @chris85 Yeah, sorry. The file itself does not have HTML, including `$row['column']`. I have a separate HTML file that has a button. When you click the button it generates a table called from a PHP file--the PHP file being what I am doing now where I am having issues.

When I apply `var_dump($row['column']);` I have the same issue, unfortunately. The row is left blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to fix my code, with some help from the code used here. The primary issue was that I used:

`if($con->query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE row1='variable1' AND row2='variable2'"))`

I was able to fix my code by using:

`$sql = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE row1='variable1' AND row2='variable2'";
 $output = $con->query($sql);`

before the if statement. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try again..

```
if($con->query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE row1='variable1' AND row2='variable2'")) {
    if($output= $con->use_result()) {
        while($row = $output->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>".$row['row1']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['row2']."</td>";
    }
}}
```

Comment: For suggesting the use of the deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) `mysql_` database extension when the OP is already using the `mysqli_` extension -1

Comment: Unfortunately, this code leaves me with the same problem. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked for me. This has also been suggested in the comments above:

```
if($con->query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE row1='variable1' AND row2='variable2'")) {
    if($output= $con->use_result()) {
        while($row = $output->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>".$row['column']."</td>";
        }
    }
}
```